# Retrieving tweet by tweet-id

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitter-streaming-api

Is it possible to stream tweets for a list of tweet-ids using tweepy or twython?
I am trying to use to Twython using 
      tweets = t.lookup_status(id=Id)

'Id' looping over a list of tweet-ids

but there are rate limitations I guess and in case of tweepy, using StreamListener, I can only get tweets for some particular track. In my case, I have a list of tweet_ids for which I need the tweet-text, created_at, source, url etc ...
Or is there any other option for this task?
I am quite new to this. Please excuse if the question is naive!

Comment: Howdy Pikakshi, does the code below work for you?

Comment: I'm glad it helped! Feel free to upvote and/or select the answer by clicking the little green check box :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite clear what it is you're after, but you can find tweets that match a certain tweet id using the following snippet (provided you have a `consumer_key`, `consumer_secret`, `access_token`, and `access_token_secret` from the Twitter API):

```
    import tweepy

    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

    api = tweepy.API(auth)

    public_tweets = api.home_timeline()

    good_tweet_ids = [555175389383774208, 555174725136437248]

    for tweet in public_tweets:
        if tweet.id in good_tweet_ids:
            print "".join(x for x in tweet.text if ord(x) < 128)
```